# How to pick second column from a PetaPoco query result?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, petapoco

Below is my code:

```
string Query = "SELECT EmpName, EmpCode FROM EmpDetail WHERE ZCode=101 ORDER BY EmpName";
var db = new PetaPoco.Database("conCustomer");
var result = db.Fetch<string>(query);
TextBox1.Text = result.ToString(); //This is giving first column
TextBox2.Text = .... // pick second column
```

I want to know how to pick the second column from the result.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you're having is that you're not using a class as part of the fetch. Try creating a simple class and performing the fetch with that:

```
public class EmpDetail
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
}

var result = db.Fetch<EmpDetail>(Query);
```

Then try iterating over that list of `EmpDetail`:

```
foreach (var detail in result) 
{
    var x = detail.EmpName; // First column
    var y = detail.EmpCode; // Second column
}
```

**EDIT:** According to [this](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/104/PetaPoco-Not-So-Poco-or-adding-support-for-dynamic) (h/t Robert Koritnik), it does look like it will support a `dynamic` query like so (*untested*):

```
foreach (var detail in db.Fetch<dynamic>(query))
{
    var x = detail.EmpName; // First column
    var y = detail.EmpCode; // Second column
}
```

Comment: I don't feel any need to create a class. Without a class, how to retrieve?